# Call of my custom module in a CMS Page not working

Tags: module, magento-1, cms

I am working on a quotation form module I would like to implement on my Shop Home Page

My config.xml is (app/code/community/Mine/Quotemodule/etc/config.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>  
        <Mine_Quotemodule>  
            <version>0.0.1</version>  
        </Mine_Quotemodule>  
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <routeurfrontend>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mine_Quotemodule</module>
                    <frontName>quotemodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </routeurfrontend>
        </routers>    
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <quotemodule>
                    <file>quotemodule.xml</file>
                </quotemodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>  
    </frontend>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <quotemodule>
                <class>Mine_Quotemodule_Block</class>
            </quotemodule>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/etc/modules/Mine_Quotemodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mine_Quotemodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Mine_Quotemodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/quotemodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
     <default>
          <reference name="content">
          </reference>
      </default>
      <routeurfrontend_index_index>
           <reference name="content">
                <block type="quotemodule/quoteformblock"  name="quoteform_quoteformblock"
                          template="quotemodule/quoteform.phtml" />
           </reference>
      </routeurfrontend_index_index>
</layout>
```

app/code/community/Mine/Quotemodule/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Mine_Quotemodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
   public function indexAction()
   {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
   }

   public function mamethodeAction()
   {
     echo 'test mamethode';
    }
}
?>
```

app/code/community/Mine/Quotemodule/Block/Quoteformblock.php
(unsued for the moment)

```
<?php
class Mine_Quotemodule_Block_Quoteformblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
     public function methodblock()
     {
         return 'informations de mon block !!';
     }
}
?>
```

and I have a app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/quotemodule/quoteform.phtml file containing my html form.

When I go to the url my www.myshop.com/quotemodule/index, It works.

I then tried to implement the form by calling the module in my CMS Home page, by adding in content :

```
{{block type="mine/quotemodule" name="quoteform_quoteformblock" template="quotemodule/quoteform.phtml"}}
```

But when loading my homepage, it is empty..

Thank you for your help,

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the block on your cms page is wrong.

I think it should be type `quotemodule/quoteformblock` the same as in the layout.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

In the calling the module in CMS Home page is not proper.
The Right module form calling is:

```
{{block type="quotemodule/quoteformblock" name="quoteform_quoteformblock" template="quotemodule/quoteform.phtml"}}
```